# How to create and modify a MySQL structure to store user names and email addresses from an HTML form

Tags: html, html-email, email

I have the following form on my website (which does nothing). How can I integrate it with a MYSQL database to store the "Name" and "Email" fields people enter?

```
<form action="" id="contactsForm">
<div class="">
<center>
<input name="name" type="name" class="moonray-form-input" id="name" required="" value="" placeholder="Enter Your Name:" data-required="true">
</center>
</div>
<div class="">
<center>
<input name="email" type="email" class="moonray-form-input" id="email" required="" value="" placeholder="Enter Your Email:" data-required="true">
</center>
</div>
<div class="">
<center>
<input type="submit" name="submit-button" value="Submit" id="submit1">
</center>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: there are plenty of tutorials. I'd start there.

Comment: You need to write server-side code.

Answer (score 2):

- First you need a web server with Php and Mysql.
- Then you need to create your Mysql database. (CREATE database ...)
- After you need to create the structure of the table in your database. (CREATE table ...)
- And you need to know what MYSQL command you want to execute everytime your form is submitted (INSERT INTO ...)

(If you need help for these 4 points it's another story **see answers below**)

If you have everything listed above, the basic idea is to use a form to send information to a php page with this syntax :

```
<form action="this_page.php">
```

You can add the method you like (for example POST)

```
<form action="this_page.php" method="POST">
```

And inside "this_page.php", you can execute the MYSQL syntax you want.

```
$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
$db_select=mysql_select_db("name_of_the_database",$connection);
$sqlquery=mysql_query("YOUR MYSQL CODE GO HERE");
```

Oh and if you use the POST method you can retrieve your variable with this syntax :

```
$_POST['name_of_the_variable']
```

ADD POST BELOW :

Okay for the points above here is an example (MYSQL CODE ONLY, can copy paste into mysql prompt) :

```
CREATE database TEST;
SHOW databases;
USE TEST;
CREATE table list_users(
    name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(40) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO list_users(name,email) VALUES ("user1","password");
INSERT INTO list_users(name,email) VALUES ("user2","password");
SELECT * FROM list_users;
```

You just need to change what you don't like and implement it into your php code.

Comment: I gave you the syntax for one, but you can use another API : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: Thanks but I don't know what goes here $sqlquery=mysql_query("YOUR MYSQL CODE GO HERE");

I would want it to just paste the "email" under email table and "name" under name table

Comment: You are confused i think. What you need to do :

1 - You create the STRUCTURE of the table (name+email)

Comment: 2 - You can add elements to this structure, with for example : INSERT INTO list_users (name,email) VALUES ("the_name","the_email")

Comment: This is well meant, but this specific user needs to learn the very basics first, from a tutorial. Otherwise this'll go on all night ("what do I need to do now?")

Answer (score 0):

Okay for the points above here is an example (MYSQL CODE ONLY, can copy paste into mysql prompt) :

```
CREATE database TEST;
SHOW databases;
USE TEST;
CREATE table list_users(
    name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(40) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO list_users(name,email) VALUES ("user1","password");
INSERT INTO list_users(name,email) VALUES ("user2","password");
SELECT * FROM list_users;
```

You just need to change what you don't like and implement it into your php code.